# getAttributes of User from SysoutEventListenerProvider [keycloak]

Tags: keycloak

there is a way to get attributes of User from SysoutEventListenerProvider? I've tried to look AdmninEvent but there is only userId. I would need to have the whole user's detail.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Pass the session from ProviderFactory

```
@Override
public EventListenerProvider create(KeycloakSession session) {
  return new SysoutEventListenerProvider(session);
}
```

and use it to accomplish what you want

```
    @Override
public void onEvent(Event event) {
    String userId = event.getUserId();
    RealmModel realm = session.realms().getRealm(event.getRealmId());
    UserModel user = session.users().getUserById(userId, realm);

    // get all attributes
    Map<String, List<String>> allAttributes = user.getAttributes(); // or
    // get Attribute by name
    String attrubute = user.getFirstAttribute("attributename");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution!!

Comment: @MirkoPaganelli if my answer helped you , please set as the accepted answer